# ValueError: Inputs have incompatible shapes. Received shapes (25, 25, 64) and (75, 75, 64)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, resnet

I am trying to build Resnet model for face recognition but I keep getting this error I tried searching on StackOverflow but nothing works properly I WOULD APPRECIATE THE HELP

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mahmo\Downloads\test\FaceRecognitionModel.py", line 84, in <module>
    layer1 = resnet(visible,64,3)
  File "c:\Users\mahmo\Downloads\test\FaceRecognitionModel.py", line 78, in resnet
    layer_out = Add()([conv3, data])
  File "C:\Users\mahmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\mahmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\merging\base_merge.py", line 74, in _compute_elemwise_op_output_shape
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Inputs have incompatible shapes. Received shapes (25, 25, 64) and (75, 75, 64)
```

My code is as follows for the model and layers used

```
bnEps = 2e-5
bnMom = 0.9
chanDim = 1

def resnet(layer_in, n_filters,s):
    data = layer_in
    stride = (s,s)
    
    #1st Convolutional Layer
    merge_input = Conv2D(n_filters, (1,1),strides = (s,s))(layer_in)        
    bn2 = BatchNormalization(axis = chanDim,epsilon=bnEps,momentum = bnMom)(merge_input)
    act2 = Activation('relu')(bn2)
    
    #2nd Convolutional Layer
    conv2 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3,3),strides= stride,use_bias = False, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(act2)  
    bn3 = BatchNormalization(axis = chanDim,epsilon=bnEps,momentum = bnMom)(conv2)
    act3 = Activation('relu')(bn3)
    
    #3rd Convolutional layer
    conv3 = Conv2D(n_filters, (1,1),use_bias = False, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(act3)  
    
    
    data = Conv2D(n_filters,(1,1),padding = 'valid',strides = (s,s))(data) # Adjusting the input size according to 3rd convolutional layer
    data = BatchNormalization()(data)  
    # add filters, assumes filters/channels last
    layer_out = Add()([conv3, data])
    layer_out = Activation('relu')(layer_out)
    return layer_out

#define model input
visible = Input(shape=(224,224, 3))
layer1 = resnet(visible,64,3)
layer2 = resnet(layer1,128,1)
layer4 = resnet(layer2,256,1)
layer5 = resnet(layer4,256,2)
layer6 = resnet(layer5,512,2)
layer7 = resnet(layer6,512,2)
layer8 = resnet(layer7,1024,2)
layert = Dropout(0.5)(layer8)
layer9 = resnet(layert,2048,2)
layert2 = Dropout(0.5)(layer9)
layer10 = resnet(layert2,4096,2)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(layer10)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)
#flatten = Flatten()(layer9)
den = Dense(2048,activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
final = Dense(5, activation="softmax")(den)
#create model
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=final)
```

So my questions are: How to match the shapes, and why this does not work? Is it the code or something else

New error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mahmo\Downloads\test\FaceRecognitionModel.py", line 130, in <module>
    history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,steps_per_epoch = 20,shuffle = True,epochs = 65)
  File "C:\Users\mahmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\mahmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend.py", line 5560, in categorical_crossentropy
    target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
ValueError: Shapes (1, 1) and (1, 5) are incompatible
```

the rest of the code that could have the error

```
#compiling model
initial_lr = 1e-5
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_lr,
    decay_steps=10000,  # You can adjust this value based on your dataset size and batch size
    decay_rate=0.9      # You can adjust this decay rate as well
)

# Use the learning rate schedule as the optimizer
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=optimizer,
    metrics=['accuracy'],
    run_eagerly=True
)
# summarize model
model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,steps_per_epoch = 20,shuffle = True,epochs = 65)
score = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train ,verbose=1)
print('Test Loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you reduce the input dimension with the stride, and padding doesn't counter that. So both your `merge_input` Conv2D layer as well as your `data` Conv2D layer reduces your 224x224 input to 75x75 (as you can see as the second shape in your error message). But then the `conv2d` layer further reduces the 75x75 output from `bn2` to 25x25 with stride (3x3).
To solve that, you could either remove the stride from either the first convolution `merge_input`or the second convolution `conv2d`, or reduce `data` to 25x25. Looking into resnet building blocks like [this one](https://paperswithcode.com/method/resnet-d), you can see that it uses only one stride 2 on both the normal connection and the skip connection.

Edit: For your new error, looks like your target data is only one number, most likely label encoded. Look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326065/cross-entropy-vs-sparse-cross-entropy-when-to-use-one-over-the-other). It should work when you switch to sparse categorical cross-entropy, or one-hot encode your target data. But without knowing how your data looks it is just a guess.

Comment: This fixed one issue for me thanks a lot but now I have issue when compiling the model I hope you can help with that

Comment: the thing when trainning i get this each epoch :  C:\Users\mahmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:1176: SyntaxWarning: In loss categorical_crossentropy, expected y_pred.shape to be (batch_size, num_classes) with num_classes > 1. Received: y_pred.shape=(1, 1). Consider using 'binary_crossentropy' if you only have 2 classes.
  return dispatch_target(*args, **kwargs)
 4/20 [=====>........................] - ETA: 1:32 - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Comment: Sure. Looks like your target data is only one number, most likely label encoded. Look here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326065/cross-entropy-vs-sparse-cross-entropy-when-to-use-one-over-the-other. It should work when you switch to sparse categorical crossentropy, or one-hot encode your target data. But without knowing how your data looks it is just a guess.

Comment: I've added my comment to my original answer to have everything in one place, but can't edit my comment anymore.